# How can I use FMDB as a Framework in an iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, c, ipad, sqlite, fmdb

I am currently developing an iPad application. At one stage, there is a series of sliders and buttons, when you press the button, it stores the value of the slider into a table. First of all, I need to use SQLite to manage the database. I found a project called FMDB that is a wrapper around SQLite for iPhone/Mac apps. I am pretty new to iOS/Objective-c developpment and want to know how you add FMDB (or an FMDB framework) into an app.

-Tristan

Comment: I know but how do you get the FMDB framework to be in the list?

Comment: Try following the core plot instructions but do it for FMDB http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download the FMDB source here: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

To import the src folder, you can just drag and drop it into Xcode's project navigator. On prompt, check to copy files in. You may then want to rename the folder from src to FMDB, and possibly create another folder to categorize external libraries as well.

Don't forget to include the libsqlite3.dylib into your project. To do this, click on your project in the navigator, click on your project's name under TARGETS, and go to Build Phases tab. Expand the Link Binary With Libraries and click the + button to add it in.